# How safe is Amazon Web Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been working with SQLite a month now and moving to MySQL. I've found about the AWS which looks pretty awesome because of their flexible big servers that can automaticly scale the power you need according to how popular your app is gonna be and how much traffic there is.

It says that you only pay for what you use.

Ok, but what if a hacker or something is gonna spam data on my database... am i then suddently the next day ending up with 10000$ bill?

So how safe is it?
Can i put a maximum value of how much traffic there can be so it will close my database or something?

Comment: Safe depends on how well you practice security. You can easily add an MFA device to your accounts. Use IAM accounts/policies to limit access to certain parts of your infrastructure. Change your password regularly.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily setup billing alerts that will let you keep tabs on how much you are spending...probably a good idea if you are worried about costs.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/05/10/announcing-aws-billing-alerts/

Comment: Yes, but the alerts aint gonna help if im not at the computer because when i realize it, its probably gonna be too late. So i would rather turn everything automaticly down rather than doing it manually.

Comment: @Assassinbeast (You can programatically monitor the CloudWatch alarm, or perhaps act on the SNS notification to handle overages.)  Please investigate the posted link before criticizing the answer...